# Connection between Darboux property and semicontinuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Is there a connection between the Darboux property (that is, the mean value propriety) and semicontinuity? That is, is there a characterization of semicontinuity that uses Darboux property (or are there other results of similar type)?